# How do i get the Stream name while using multiple Streaming?

Tags: java, media, wowza

I publish a live Stream from client to server. There are many clients (many Streams).

Now I want to get the details of that Streaming. So I used Log fields. That fields return some value but I didn't get the stream name. I use the wowza server for streaming.

```
for(String s : WMSLoggerIDs.FD_ALL) {
    System.out.println(s+":      "+WMSLoggerFactory.getGlobalLogValue(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void play(IClient client, RequestFunction function, AMFDataList params)
        {
           System.out.println(getParamString(params, PARAM1)); 
        }
```

*If You use the play function and passing these arguments ,you will get the Stream Name*